# SQL Server trigger - Making a data field unavailable

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, triggers, sql-insert

Completely new to SQL Server - so please bear with me.

I am trying to create a trigger which is supposed to mark a data column (in my case a `BikeID`) as unavailable when a rental record is added that makes reference to the `BikeID`.

This is what I got so far but not quite sure how to go about it.

```
create trigger BikeUnavailable
on SA_Rental
after insert, update
as
begin
    declare @BikeID varchar(50)

    if exists(SELECT * FROM SA_Rental
        where bikeid = @BikeID)

    begin


end
```

I was thinking along the lines of making the index unreachable or something but completely blank as to how to go about it.

All help is very appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

So after implementing the suggestion I keep getting the following errors:

[image]

Here is my trigger code:

```
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[BikeUnavailable]    Script Date: 
9/9/2018 2:05:33 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER trigger [dbo].[BikeUnavailable]
on [dbo].[SA_Rental]
after insert, update
as
begin
    declare @BikeID varchar(50)

    --update the flag as unavailable in the main table 

    update SA_Bike
    set BikeID = 'Unavailable'
    where BikeId = inserted.BikeID


end
```

Comment: Please post your code **as text** and properly format it - don't post screenshots of code!!

Comment: The syntax for an update is update tablename set columnname

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your replies. I have pasted the edited code as text, @P.Salmon I have put the table name as the 'update' now, but I still get an error below for the 'where clause' which says: The multi-part identifier "Inserted.BikeID" could not be bound.

Answer (score 0):

You can use logical tables (aka magic tables) in SQL (`inserted` and `deleted`) to update the field in the table when a records is inserted into SA_Rental table.

Sample code below:

```
create trigger BikeUnavailable
on SA_Rental
after insert, update
as
begin
    declare @BikeID varchar(50)

    --update the flag as unavailable in the main table 

    update *table_name*
    set *flag_column_name* = *'Unavailable'*
    where BikeId = inserted.BikeID

end
```

[More Insight](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2342/understanding-sql-server-inserted-and-deleted-tables-for-dml-triggers/)

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. I've added your solution in and it seems to work fine but I keep getting errors where it keeps saying my column name is invalid?

Comment: Please provide the error you are seeing and the code which you are using.

Comment: I've added the error and the code to the original question as screenshots. Please could you check this and let me know what you think. Thanks.

Comment: There is syntax error after update: 
use-> update SA_Rental
    set BikeID = 'Unavailable'
    where BikeId = inserted.BikeID

but I was thinking you were updating some reference table after getting an entry in the SA_Rental table.

Comment: It still gives me the error for the 'where clause' which says: The multi-part identifier "Inserted.BikeID" could not be bound. I am referring to a the actual SA_Bike table, the SA_Rental table contains the BikeID as a 'foreign key'.

Comment: include 'select * from inserted' in the trigger definition and see if you are getting the right column name there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179705/discussion-between-noname788-and-satishcse).